# Stripe elements credit card autocomplete / auto fill not working in Ionic mobile app iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, ionic-framework, stripe-payments

I am using Stripe elements to collect credit card details.
If I deploy my Ionic app to web it works fine on iOS safari and offers to auto fill with my saved credit card as expected.

However if I deploy the same app to mobile it does not offer auto fill on the same device.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Comment: Are you referring to auto fill as a browser's function? That could be tricky with ionic/mobile. 

If you use Stripe's built in API for saving credit card to Customer server-side, I think you can achieve the same UX regardless of frontend client

Comment: @orakaro Yes the browser autofill although as it is a mobile app it would be in a webview.  I already save the credit card to the Stripe customer if that is what you mean.  Not sure how that would help as I want a new user to have the card details auto filled from their saved card on the device.

Comment: I'm willing to use any option to solve this such as not using Stripe elements.

Comment: Stripe won't ever response back the real card number (After it's tokenized it won't leave Stripe server). Stripe only response back the last4 at most (https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/object#payment_method_object-card-last4) So if you are looking for autofill it is relied to Safari.

But with last4 you can build an UI yourself by displaying "Already saved card" with asterisks and last4, and allow your customer to choose on your UI. Internally you can use the PaymentMethod Id from Stripe API to identify cards

Comment: @orakaro thanks I already let the user choose from cards saved in Stripe. I am looking for a method for new cards.